# Why am I not able to get data to my AngularJS component via bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to have an AngularJS component, `messageDisplay`, which can take a property `message` (as in, just a propery on its HTML tag in the index.html file) and then display that. Based on all the example code I've been able to find, this should work, but it isn't working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Angular sandbox</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="components/message-display.component.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="app">
        <message-display message="Hi"></message-display>
    </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
const app = angular.module("app", []);
```

message-display.component.js

```
app.component(
        "messageDisplay",
        {
            bindings: {
                message: "<"
            },
            template: "<h1>Message: {{$ctrl.message}}</h1>"
        }
    )
```

I just get a page with the text "Message:" and nothing else. I would expect to get "Message: Hi".

Comment: In your example Angular looks for variable Hi, which is not defined. So, pass desired string as a string using single quotes: <message-display message="'Hi'"></message-display> Or change binding type to @ as proposed in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass strings to one-way (`"<"`) bindings, use single-quotes:

```
<message-display message="'Hi'"></message-display>
```

otherwise it will be evaluated as an AngularJS expression, e.g. `$scope.Hi`

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component(
        "messageDisplay",
        {
            bindings: {
                message: "<"
            },
            template: "<h1>Message: {{$ctrl.message}}</h1>"
        }
)
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
        <message-display message="'Hi'"></message-display>
</body>
```

---

## Update

> Where would you recommend I learn this stuff? The whole "bindings" concept and these mysterious <, &, =, @ symbols don't seem to be covered in the tutorial

For more informtion, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

In general, I avoid two-way (`"="`) binding because it makes the migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.

I also avoid attribute (`"@"`) binding for consistency reasons. I don't need to remember which attributes take an AngularJS expression and which attributes need mustaches (`{{ }}`).

Comment: Thanks. Where would you recommend I learn this stuff? The whole "bindings" concept and these mysterious <, &, =, @ symbols don't seem to be covered in the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00), I only pieced together this information from scattered mentions found by googling things like "angular pass data to component".

Comment: See update. I apologize. In my haste to get an answer out I neglected to include links to the docs. Generally avoid using `=` and `@`. Just use `<` and `&`.

Answer (score 1):

hey binding should be '@', use this:-

```
app.component(
        "messageDisplay",
        {
            bindings: {
                message: "@"
            },
            template: "<h1>Message: {{$ctrl.message}}</h1>"
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `<` **one way binding** :- when we just want to read a parameter
   from a parent scope and not update it.
2. `@` this is for **String Parameters**

```js
const app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.component(
        "messageDisplay",
        {
              bindings: {
                message: "@"
              },
              template: "<h1>Message: {{$ctrl.message}}</h1>"
        }
    )
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
        <message-display message="Hi"></message-display>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
-->
```

Mode details blog -> http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/dissecting-bindings-in-angularjs/

Comment: Did you read the blog you quoted? It ends with `Also, & can go rotate on a stick.`